# How to put HREFs in Ember template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I must be missing something simple because I'm not finding the answer to my question anywhere. I've done due RTFM diligence, and am now resorting to asking my question here.

In short, I want to put a simple `<a>` tag in an Ember template, but the extra Ember mark up to make the object dynamic is breaking the URL itself.

My template looks like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="event-nav">
    <a href="{{ obj.url }}">{{ obj.display_name }}</a>
</script>
```

This, of course, results in something like this sitting in the DOM itself:

```
<a class="event-name logo" href="/&lt;script id='metamorph-0-start' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script id='metamorph-0-end' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;"><script id="metamorph-1-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>Object Name<script id="metamorph-1-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script></a>
```

So in short, how do I make it do?

Much thanks.

Comment: When you get an answer to this question, please consider improving the docs in the area where you expected to find the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use the ['bindAttr'-helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_bindAttr) for this kind of use case:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="event-nav">
   <a {{bindAttr href="obj.url" alt="obj.displayName"}}>{{obj.displayName}}</a>
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Michael. I'd read a whole bunch of Ember documentation pages, but hadn't stumbled on that nugget.